# Rendered image size by KonvaJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, frontend, konvajs

I created Stage, created Layers
Generated some Path's, added it to Layer
Can I calculate width of rendered image? If image overflow, i want get it real width

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `node.getClientRect()` function for your Path node.
It will give you position and size of the node.